# How to fix "No package docker-1.13.1 available" when trying to install Docker on RHEL Server 7.8?

Tags: docker, openshift, rhel, openshift-origin, epel

I'm trying to install Docker on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo). I'm following the OKD [host preparation instructions](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install/host_preparation.html).

When I run `yum install docker-1.13.1`, I get:

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, search-disabled-repos
rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms                                                                                | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms                                                                                          | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhui-client-config-server-7                                                                                      | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
(1/6): rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms/7Server/x86_64/updateinfo                                               |  35 kB  00:00:00
(2/6): rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms/7Server/x86_64/group                                                    |  124 B  00:00:00
(3/6): rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms/7Server/x86_64/primary                                                  |  66 kB  00:00:00
(4/6): rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms/7Server/x86_64/group                                                              | 772 kB  00:00:00
(5/6): rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms/7Server/x86_64/updateinfo                                                         | 3.8 MB  00:00:00
(6/6): rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms/7Server/x86_64/primary                                                            |  45 MB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms                                                                                               243/243
rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms                                                                                                     29237/29237
No package docker-1.13.1 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use RHEL for OKD? Use CentOS instead and you'll have that package out of the box

Otherwise follow the OCP instruction instead OKD, but then you need a subscription for RHEL and OCP :
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/host_preparation.html